# Download Web Content - long downloading

Tags: java, android, regex, android-asynctask

I've been learning Java for a few months. Nowadays I'm creating an app which downloads web content and shows the data in a `ListView`. The problem is that everything takes a very long time - about 25 second from the launch of the app to fill the list with elements. What is more, there is no difference between it running on a real device or an Android emulator.

In my opinion, the Java code is not bad because most of it is from my course on Udemy.

How can I improve this? Where is the problem?

Reports from logcat and AVD setting [ss]:
[image: Reports from logcat and AVD setting [ss]]

Here's my code below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.user.legionisciapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> desc = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            String result = "";

            try {

                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();

                }

                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        try {

            String result = downloadTask.execute("https://www.legionisci.com").get();
            String[] resultSplit = result.split("<div id=\"mecze\">");
            result = resultSplit[0];
            resultSplit = result.split("<div id=\"listanewsow\">");
            result = resultSplit[1];

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("class=\"b\" title=\"(.*?)\">");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(result);

            while (m.find()) {

                titles.add(m.group(1));

            }

            p = Pattern.compile("></a>(.*?)</div>");
            m = p.matcher(result);

            while (m.find()) {

                desc.add(m.group(1));

            }

            p = Pattern.compile("alt=\"\" class=\"zl\" /></a>(.*?)<");
            m = p.matcher(result);

            while (m.find()) {

                urls.add("https://www.legionisci.com" + m.group(1));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {


            newsList.add(new News(R.drawable.ll, titles.get(i), desc.get(i)));


            NewsListAdapter newsListAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(this, R.layout.news_list, newsList);
            listView.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);


        }
    }
}
```

**News.java**

```
package com.example.user.legionisciapp;

    public class News {

        int image;

        String title, desc;

        public News(int image, String title, String desc) {
            this.image = image;
            this.title = title;
            this.desc = desc;
        }

        public int getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }
    }
```

**NewsListAdapter.class**

```
package com.example.user.legionisciapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class NewsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {

    Context ctx;
    int resource;
    List<News> newsList;

    public NewsListAdapter (Context ctx, int resource, List<News> newsList){
        super(ctx, resource, newsList);

        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.newsList = newsList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list, null);

        TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        TextView desc = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
        ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.thumb);

        News news = newsList.get(position);

        title.setText(news.getTitle());
        desc.setText(news.getDesc());
        image.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(news.getImage()));

        return view;

    }
}
```

Comment: As you can imagine this is my own idea to extract the part of site which I was interested in. I had a problem because <div id="listanewsow"> was about 3/4 of full page so I can't extract this with a single split of full html code in "result". I know there is a probably a better way to do it.

Can you let me know if there is any?

Comment: For a start, use an HTML parser instead, e.g. [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). And read: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** do something like this:

```
String result = downloadTask.execute("https://www.legionisci.com").get();
```

That is not the right way to use an AsyncTask! The problem is that the async task is executed in a background thread but if you do `.get()` the main thread is paused until the async task finishes his job. So this is the reason of the long wait at startup.

What you have to do is:

Starting the task this way

```
downloadTask.execute("https://www.legionisci.com");
```

Using the `onPostExecute(String result)` method (executed on the main thread) to get the result and update the UI .

More on this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: You are right. I should use `onPostExecute(String result)` . For testing your solution I've created a new very simple project. There is only MainActivity.class and AsyncTask and... it happened again..

MainAcitivity.class - https://codeshare.io/5N9VPr

Of course I added into Manifest permission for Internet. Did i do something wrong?

Screen of Logs: https://imgur.com/a/TXXndyA

Comment: @Janek well there's another problem: garbage collector is called too many times. This usually happens when you allocate too many objects. I can see that in the task you read from the InputStream with a while cycle. So try to optimize that cycle allocating less objects or using something different to decode the stream(https://stackoverflow.com/q/309424/9796205)

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream` works perfect for me. So the problem was incorrect InputStreamReader... Thank you!